# SSH key login not working

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, debian-wheezy

i am having some problems logging in to one server to SSH via a key

this is the client output: ssh 'importer@pdw.me' -p 2201 -v

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to pdwhost [107.191.34.35] port 2201.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/importer/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/importer/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/importer/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: identity file /home/importer/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/importer/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/importer/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA cd:23:7f:17:0c:a3:97:37:71:97:ba:d0:0d:d6:7f:43
debug1: Host '[pdwhost]:2201' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/importer/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/importer/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/importer/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/importer/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

and this is the output on the server (when i start with -debug)

/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 22

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type ECDSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.ECDSA-256
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.ECDSA-256
debug1: private host key: #2 type 3 ECDSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='22'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 144.76.186.42 port 58956
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 103/65534 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user importer service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: initializing for "importer"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "static.42.clients.your-server.de"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user importer service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable [preauth]
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/importer/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for importer from 144.XXX port 58956 ssh2
Connection closed by 144.XXX [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 17937
```

not sure what is going on here, SSHD kills itself when the client tries to login.
Its a Debian 7 in an openVZ container (host is also Debian 7)

SSH Login via password works fine, I just disabled it for the purpose of testing the Key login, it always asked for a password when trying the key login (as key didnt work).

---

I set the %HOME% to 700, .ssh is also set to 700, files inside to 500

I copied the key with ssh-copy-id (and did it a second time). The keys I am using are a bit older, so I did not create them just for this SSH client. I cant find any errors in the authorized_keys

this from the sshd_config

```
RSAAuthentication yes 
PubkeyAuthentication yes
 AuthorizedKeysFile   %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Still get failed public key.

---

btw. in the meanwhile I tried to access the same server from another client:
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-id-copy
ssh ..

and it worked, so it must be something on the client above

Comment: forgot to explain, the port 2201 is rerouted to 22 via the openvz-host, so ports are correct

Comment: As much as I detest asking stupid followup questions: Can you confirm that /home/importer, /home/importer/.ssh, and /home/importer/.ssh/authorized_keys are owned by uid 1000 (importer?) and **not** root?

Comment: yes, ownership is correct, I also tested it from a another client (debian 7 also) and it is working from there, this means i must look at the client.

Answer (score 0):

First check the basics:

1. the contents of your .ssh/authorized_keys are correct? No extra line breaks in the public key?
2. the file permissions are correct? sshd can be very strict about this: you should see lots 600, or even 400 (read-only for root). Quoting your log:

`debug1: trying public key file /home/importer/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for importer from 144.XXX port 58956 ssh2`

3. [sshd can even be annoyed about other folders' permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37164/ssh-and-home-directory-permissions)

Comment: plz see my comments in the original question

Comment: Oops, sorry :-/

Comment: So is the key you are using modern & secure enough? How old are they? I.e. what type of encryption was used to generate the key: e.g. ssh-rsa, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,... It should show in your 'known_hosts'

Comment: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, cant really remember how I generated it.

Comment: Don't worry, that one should be good enough. I hope another Debian veteran can help you. I do not like the version of openSSL: "OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013"

Comment: And both Debian machines are patched to a matching revision of openSSH: "sshd version OpenSSH_6.0p1". Hmm.

Comment: Also, if you are hosting anything web-related on this box: make sure it is patched, debian7 is from before heartbleed & shellshock.

Comment: just ran apt-get upgrade/update on both vz's, no surprise, still the same